# How to set different font for different language by using i18next?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

***React i18next***

**I am using two languages English and Arabic in my project I am using i18next react i want to use two different
fonts for Arabic and English
i want to use DIN Next LT for Arabic
and Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif for English**

Answer (score 2):

Add a new class in the CSS file. and conditionaly render that class based on the language selected. Use Dynamic styling.

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
<div classname={i18n.language === 'en' ?  'english-class': 'other-language'}></div>
```

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: use i18n.resolvedLanguge instead of i18n.language

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current language by accessing i18next.resolvedLanguage https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage

So based on that information you can use a different font.